# Unable to connect to Cisco openconnect in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: vpn, cisco, openconnect

Today I have decided to upgrade my os from 18.04 to 19.10
I use openconnect with the terminal by this command :

```
sudo openconnect de.cisadd2.com
```

Then I enter my username and password and it would always connect but after upgrading my os to 19.10, It has a weird error although it says it is connected.

```
POST https://de.cisadd2.com/auth
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 CONNECTED
CSTP connected. DPD 90, Keepalive 32400
Connected as 10.10.199.191, using SSL, with DTLS in progress
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(PSK)-(AES-256-GCM).
Error: ipv4: Invalid values in header for route get request.
Error: ipv4: Invalid values in header for route get request.
Error: ipv4: Invalid values in header for route get request.
```

Comment: I snipped out the `ip` usage messages because that just obscures the actual messages, which are that there's invalid values in header(s) for the route requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` uses the now unsupported `ip get route $NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN` syntax.
I fixed that by changing the line 261 to

```
$IPROUTE route add `$IPROUTE route get "$NETWORK" | fix_ip_get_output | sed -e "s/^$NETWORK\$/$NETWORK\/$NETMASKLEN/"`
```

Comment: A recent vpnc-scripts package should fix this, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=955016 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vpnc-scripts/+bug/1871184